# Error when passing symbol as argument in a function for fby in kdb

Tags: kdb

length error when passing symbol as argument to a function for fby.

```
Syntax: (aggr;data) fby group
```

I have a table:

```
 t:([] sym:10?`IBM`AMZN`MSFT; mkt:10?`m1`m2`m3; px:10?100.)
```

When trying to run below it fails with length error

```
{select from t where px=(min;px) fby x}`sym
```

How to pass group as an argument to a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sym` variable (i.e. the column `sym`) is not in the context (as it normally would be in a select statement), because you are passing it in from outside the select statement. So here you are just passing in a variable of symbol-type with content "sym" (hence the length error). The following works, passing in the column `` t[`sym] ``:

```
{select from t where px=(min;px) fby x}[t`sym]
```

If your intention is to group by various columns, you may want to look at using [functional select](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/). e.g.

```
?[t;enlist (=;`px;(fby;(enlist;min;`px);`sym));0b;()]
sym  mkt px      
-----------------
MSFT m2  17.80839
AMZN m1  30.17723
IBM  m2  41.1597
```

Or passing the column name through to a function:

```
{?[t;enlist (=;`px;(fby;(enlist;min;`px);x));0b;()]}`sym
```